# Possible to create JavaFX Application object?

Tags: java, javafx

Would it be possible to make an Application object from javaFX?

```
public class Constructor
{
    public Constructor()
    {
        Application a = new Application()
        {
            @Override
            public void start(Stage window) throws Exception
            {

            }
        };
        a.launch();
    }
}
```

It currently gives me this when I try to run it:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: class net.whiteautumn.lightcast.Constructor is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application

This, I presume, is caused by the class `Constructor` not extending `Application`.
Any way of getting around this or is that the only way to ever launch JavaFX applications?

EDIT:
I know how to start a javaFX application. What I want to to make an application and have it in an object. Is this possible or no?

Comment: look here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.launch()` is a static method, therefore `a.launch()` is equivalent to `Application.launch()`. This means that it will try to launch an application of the class that calls it, which is `Constructor` class.

The correct way to do it is:

```
private static class MyApp extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception
    {

    }
};

Application.launch(MyApp.class, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should extend Application to initializing JavaFX Toolkit; and override start method to show your form(JavaFx stage). obviously, you need main static method to run application.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.CircleBuilder;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Constrcutor extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Abacus");
        Pane root = new Pane();

        Circle circle = CircleBuilder.create()
            .radius(20)
            .centerX(20)
            .centerY(20)
            .build();
        root.getChildren().add(circle);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```